# Strange way of notifying that 20 Help and Improvements have been edited

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, help-improvement

When I edited my 20th item from the "Help and Improvement" category, the following showed up:

[image]

Looks like a normal screen, except that the "Next" button is missing, despite being clearly mentioned in the instructions. I would expect a notice about why there is no next button, and a link to return to the main review page, as there would be in the other review queues.

Comment: This may come up only now because so far almost nobody has had the nerf to suffer through the 60+ review items getting 20 decent posts usually requires

Comment: It was a good day for editing, what can I say.

Comment: Also, who said the posts were decent?

Comment: By "decent" I meant "Not so awful you wouldn't even want to touch them with a close vote lest you taint yourself"

Comment: Well, there was a badge at stake. Suddenly my civilized squeamishness disappeared. Thankfully, it's back now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should now say "You have reached the daily review limit. Please come back tomorrow." instead.

Please let me know if for some reason it doesn't!

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I will check it out as opportunity permits and let you know.

Comment: I am not sure that the solution works the way it should. Should I post a new question, edit this one, or something else?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you describe what's happening in a comment? And/or show me a screenshot?

Comment: The message about reaching the daily limit is there. 1) It would be nice if the number 20 was mentioned somewhere, as it is for the other queues. 2) There is no link to return to the review page. 3) When I click back over my reviews, at least one of them (possibly one I skipped) has a message saying "Thank you for reviewing 20 questions; come back in 6 hours to continue reviewing", with an **active** edit button. Where do you want me to post the screenshots?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Link them in a comment here? You can upload them to our Imgur instance from a question or answer form.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Here goes: the slightly [inconsistent-with-other-queues notice page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wVXfl.png) and the [previous question that has an active edit button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B3vCA.png).